# Use of new and delete in C++

Tags: c++

I need help in understanding when shall I use the following options

```
char *a = new char();
```

and

```
char *a = new char[sizeof(int)+1];
```

and how the respective memory freeing calls should be made?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/

Comment: Before understanding *when* to use them, you need to understand *what* they do. Do you?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fist one allocates a single char. You delete it with:

```
delete a;
```

The second one allocates an array of chars. The length you have chosen is a little strange. You deallocate it with:

```
delete[] a;
```

Now... I hope you don't think you can put a stringified number in the second `a` (something like `"123456"`, because you'll need many more bytes. Let's say at least 12 if an `int` is 32 bits. There is a funny formula to calculate the minimum length necessary. It's an approximation of the log10 https://stackoverflow.com/a/2338397/613130

To be clear, on my machine `sizeof(int)` == 4, but in an `int` I can put `-2147483648` that is 10 digits plus the `-`, so 11 (plus the zero terminator)

Answer (score 17):

Any time you use `new T`, you have to call `delete` on the resulting pointer afterwards.

Any time you use `new T[n]`, you have to call `delete[]` on the resulting pointer afterwards.

And that's really all there is to it.

But note that you typically shouldn't use them at all.

If you need a string, don't allocate a char array. Just declare a `std::string` (without using `new`). If you need an array whose size is determined at runtime, don't allocate an array. Declare a `std::vector` (without using `new`).

Answer (score 5):

None of the expressions you show make much sense.

Also, as a general rule, never use an explicit `delete` (leave that to smart pointers and collections), and try to avoid using any explicit `new`.

For simple strings with `char` elements, just use

```
std::string a;
```

This is an example of leaving the `new`-ing and `delete`-ing to a library class (which is strongly preferable), in this case `std::string`.

Include the `<string>` header to get a declaration of the `std::string` type.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *a = new char();
```

This creates a pointer to a single initialized `char`.

```
char *a = new char;
```

Creates a pointer to a single uninitialized `char`.

```
char *a = new char[sizeof(int)+1];
```

Creates a dynamically allocated char array, of size `sizeof(int)+1`, i.e. an uninitialized c-string of size `sizeof(int)+1`. Probably 5 or 9, depending on `sizeof(int)`.

```
char *a = new char[sizeof(int)+1]();
```

The same, but the string is initialized.

You need to explicitly free the memory with `delete` for a single `char*` and `delete[]` for the `char` array.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing worth pointing out as well as the other answers is do not mix the two statements up - you should know whether you allocated a pointer or an array to `char* c` so that:

1. You call the correct `delete`/`delete[]` operator when cleaning up memory
2. You do not try accessing data beyond the pointer's scope.

For example, if you did:

```
// Create a pointer to a single char and set the value
char* c = new char();
*c = 'a';

// Access the pointer using array syntax
char tmp1 = c[0];    // Works, returns 'a'
char tmp2 = c[1];    // Illegal!
```

Because there are no safe-guards on pointers trying to access `c[1]` would do something, but in this context it will *not* return what you expect, it will most likely return memory stored after the `char* c` pointer or random memory.

Comment: c[1] is *(c+1) by definition, so it's not "random memory".
It is a well defined memory location. The problem is that it is most likely used for something else... so yes, it is "illegal" to access it that way (unless you know what you are doing, of course!)

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia I simply used the word "random" to mean `c[1]` would give you data that could be anything. But you are correct, thanks for clarifying