# how to use new[ ] and delete[ ] operator in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm currently learning C++, I already did this activity which I need to convert the array from uppercase to lowercase vice versa:

```
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    cout << "Enter anything: ";
    cin.getline(str, 100);

    //upper to lower vice versa
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (str[i] == 0x20)
        {
            continue;
        }
        str[i] ^= 0x20;
    }
    cout << "output: " << str;

return 0;

}
```

But they want me to use new[] and delete[] operator so I will no longer declare the numbers in array which is this part char str[100];
, I already tried to use it but the concept makes me confuse.

Any suggestion? any help will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be using `std::string`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of new and delete in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698865/use-of-new-and-delete-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

```
int main(){
    char *str;
    int sz = 0;

    std::cout << "enter number of characters: ";
    std::cin >> sz;

    str = new char[sz + 1];

    std::cout << "Enter anything: ";
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.getline(str, sz + 1);

    //upper to lower vice versa
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        if (str[i] == 0x20)
        {
            continue;
        }
        str[i] ^= 0x20;
    }
    std::cout << "output: " << str;

    delete[] str;
    return 0;
}
```

With *new* you allocate memory on the heap, with *delete[]* you deallocate the memory.
Note: you have to assign *sz + 1* as the size of the array since, the *getline* puts the *0 character* at the end.

Comment: hi Attila I tried this but there's an error: enter number of characters: 2
Enter anything: output:  φ▌▌▌▌  .ù- .%   "   $   #           8ià Xià ·ià ■ià         $   !   $   ó"      ·ià c  | u S E r

Answer (score 0):

I advice you from now on to look info in [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/)! It really is a good help if you are starting!

```
char* userInput;
int length;
std::cout<<"Input the length of the array!"<<std::endl;
std::cin>>length;
std::cout<<"Creating memory!"<<std::endl;
userInput=new char[length+1];
```

Now imagine you want to create a matrix (An array of arrays).

You first do as done above, and then, for the number of arrays in the array, in a `for`loop, for example, you do the new the same way.

`delete[] userInput;`
To delete de allocated memory.

As for the matrix example I was talking about, same thing: you first delete in the loop (because if you delete the first array, you cannot access the allocated memory of the arrays inside it!), and after you "delete" this memory from the arrays, you delete the memory of the array!