# Why does this simple C++ program fail to link? I've followed as closely as possible all the articles

Tags: c++, hyperlink

I have a program composed of multiple classes, many of which refer to each other. So as per recommendations I create a prototype for each one as a header file. Any module that requires another gets an appropriate #include. The files compile but fail to link and I can't figure out why. Here's an example reduced to the minimum. First a prototype, data.h:

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

class Data {
    public:
        int get();
        void set(int);
        Data();
};

#endif
```

Next is the implementation file, data.cpp:

```
class Data {
    private:
        int content;

    public:
        int get() {
            return content;
        }

        void set(int value) {
            content = value;
        }

        Data() {}
};
```

And finally the main program, test.cpp:

```
#include "data.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Data* data = new Data();
  data->set(5);
  int n = data->get();
  return 0;
};
```

I compile with

```
g++ -c test.cpp data.cpp
```

No errors there so I link with

```
g++ test.o data.o
```

and the following errors result:

```
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `Data::Data()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `Data::set(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `Data::get()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A **definition** (or *implementation*) of `get` would look like this: `int Data::get() { return content; }`

Comment: What resource do you use to learn C++?

Comment: data.cpp must include data.h. If you did it, you would catch ODR vialations.

Comment: In addition to the above, try inspecting the contents of `data.o` with `nm data.o`. You will see it does not define any of the symbols needed by `test.o` (check with `nm -C test.o`)

Comment: This is undefined behavior. Wherever you're getting these kinds of "recommendations" from, stop. Don't ever, ever, get "recommendations" for creating a header file and an implementation file that does not `#include` that header file, but defines its own completely different class. This is not what header files are for, this is undefined behavior, and a violation of one of C++'s fundamental rules: the One Definition Rule. Try learning C++ not from random "articles" but [from good C++ textbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help and useful pointers. I can now see several places I've been going wrong. Thanks also for the advice about books, but I spend most of my time with Python and JS and don't want to become a professional C++ programmer. I just want to improve the Arduino code I've been knocking out in my spare time. I'm quite willing to make mistakes and learn from them, using the Internet as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the class method definition and implementation in the same file, you can just have the following code in your data.h:

```cpp
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

class Data {
    private:
        int content;

    public:
        int get() {
            return content;
        }

        void set(int value) {
            content = value;
        }

        Data() {}
};
#endif
```

If you want to move the implementation to a cpp file (read here about this concept: [Why have header files and .cpp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/)), you can have the following code:

data.h:

```cpp
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

class Data {
    public:
        int get();
        void set(int);
        Data();
};

#endif
```

data.cpp

```
#include "data.h" // This one is important here

int Data::get() 
{
    return content;
}

void Data::set(int value) {
    content = value;
}

Data::Data() {
}
```

P.S. Also, you have memory leak, because of `Data* data` in test.cpp - google or see this: [Use of new and delete in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698865/)